# South Africa - border hopping or overstay in order to extend 30 days entry permit

Tags: visas, south-africa

I’m facing the situation which forces me to extend my 30days entry permit either by going to Swaziland and returning to RSA or overstaying in RSA. I’m writing to enquire about your very recent experiences with both methods.

That's the rough plan:

15.12 I fly from Windhoek to Maputo via Johannesburg on one booking. It appears that I will unfortunately have to recheck luggage in Joburg, which means undergoing immigration clearance and obtaining a 30 days entry permit (which is applicable for Polish citizens).

28.12 I plan to come back to RSA from Maputo by land.

28.01 I plan to leave RSA by yacht from Cape Town.

In case I get the 30days entry permit when in transit via Joburg (which based on my comprehensive research will probably happen), it won’t be enough to make for the whole stay until I leave RSA on 28.01.

Therefore I consider to visit Swaziland on approx. 11.01 and leave for RSA on 16.01 in order to obtain the new entry permit. The question is what the duration of the new permi will be. I’ve found some mixed information – some claim that it will be 30 days again, but some say it will be only 7 or 14 days. What are your recent experiences – have you tried this trick? What was the duration of your next permit – 7/14/30?

In case I obtain 7 (which is too short, contrary to 14), I will consider to overstay in SA. What will the procedure exactly look like when leaving RSA after overstaying? Do I only get the „undesirable person” status for one year, or are there any other consequences? Will they let me just leave the country by the yacht?

I’d appreciate sharing your recent experiences.

Best wishes,
Piotr

Comment: Why not apply at the South African embassy with the relevant documents and itinerary? While you can get 30 days without a visa, you can apply for a visa and get a longer *legal* period?

Comment: @RodneyHawkins it's not only a matter of time in this case, but also a matter of number of entries. There is only single entry tourist visa available, and in my case switching flights in Joburg would be considered as a first entry. Coming back to RSA through the land border would be considered as a second entry which I will not be entitled to using single entry visa.

Comment: Could you split this into two separate questions? Thank you.